# Centerally aligned text over ImageView in android Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

How to display text on android ImageView with Linear Layout. I found many examples on stack overflow for this purpose but all are for Relative Layout, Frame Layout But I am not getting it in Linear Layout.

I have tried for `android:text="My Text"` But its not working.

Please suggest me if its possible to do so. If so how can it be done.

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/share_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="text"
    android:background="@drawable/iosbutton" />
```

This is the Image attached to this ImageView on which I want to display text in the center.

[image]

Comment: Take a TexView or Button set its background as above image and setText for them..

Comment: @pragnani I cant change the element type because it already coded by one of the developers and she has not allowed to change the type.

Comment: Try to convince her it might not be the best to "not allow" changes like this.

Comment: @MaciejGórski I talked to her she got angry and left the thing as it is But I told her that if you can change something little bit I will do what ever you want. Thanks MaciejGórski.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Use this method

```
public BitmapDrawable writeOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text){

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Paint paint = new Paint(); 
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);  
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
    paint.setTextSize(20); 

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, bm.getHeight()/2, paint);

    return new BitmapDrawable(bm);
}
```

call like this

```
ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
image.setImageDrawable(writeOnDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Hello"));
```

Comment: This is funny solution, although not complete: hardcoded font size in pixels and wrong positioning.

Comment: @MaciejGórski If you find the comments below question, I have already suggested him to use TextView or Button, Before you comment on somebody's answer as correct. And also this is not a big task to change the font size dynamically based on the image size, he'll take care of that...What is fun in that.?

Comment: @pragnani Ya that is what I want But One more thing can't it be done ion xml only. All my today's votes are exhausted I can't make you an up vote but I will be doing it tomorrow.

Comment: @Nikhil Not possible from Xml

Comment: @Pragnani. Okkkk thanks. I know previously also helped me some where. Thnak you can I have ur mail ID.

Comment: @Pragnani +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be an ImageView?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/share_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/iosbutton" />
```

Comment: This answer is correct (or use Button if this is id/share_button). For whatever strange reason if you cannot change the share_button type, you may always add TextView to the layout and align it on top of share_button. Easy when using RelativeLayout: layout_alignTop, _alignLeft, etc. all set to share_button.

Comment: @MaciejGórski But his requirement is to use ImageView check the comments below question..And this doesn't provide answer

Comment: @Pragnani Ya you are absolutely right. MaciejGórski This is not what I want.

Comment: @Pragnani undelete it let me see.